# Feasibility of a service oriented concept for a device architecture

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, architectural-patterns, soa

Assume a device using Raspberry Pi to control some hardware. This diagram tries to clarify the components:

[image: Diagram]

[SOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) concept feasibility is being explored right now. The motivations are:

- Components in different programming languages
- Need for maintainable components
- Need to support desktop, phone, etc.
- ...

Would the SOA concept be a proper option?

I'm just curious does anyone has any other architecture style in mind which might be suitable but I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: see [Green fields, blue skies, and the white board - what is too broad?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6961/31260)

Comment: Recommend you using a design method to get a better sense of your architecture. The above diagram is conflating separate levels of concern. C4 Design might be up your alley.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another nice reply received:

> I have a few comments.
>
> 1. ...
> 2. You don't need pointers. You're asking a system architect to work
>    for free.
>
> The first thing you need to do is get a copy of this book
>
> https://www.theminimumyouneedtoknow.com/soa_book.html
>
> **Actually read it** Don't try to wing it by skimming a few lines of source code. ... You need to understand the *concepts* in that book. One of
> the huge concepts you need to understand is *throttling* or more
> correctly, *throttle control*. Your drawing has given zero
> consideration to that and it is the first thing your design needs to
> have. You generally can't bolt it on at the end. Just because you
> don't think anyone will hit it with 10,000 requests per second doesn't
> mean that won't happen.
>
> The book I pointed you to ... covers creating services
> on a host (OpenVMS) using ACMS (Application Control Management
> System). There are Linux type things like Tuxedo (not quite as good)
> and probably some free stuff by now. What you need to learn from the
> book is how to design and create *restartable units of work*. That's a
> completely foreign concept for people who only develop on x86 and less
> architectures. It's most of your week every week when you work on big
> systems.
>
> The PC mentality is:
>
> Open connection - keep connection open while device is operating for
> minutes/hours/days - report back on same connection status - report
> back final completion - close connection.
>
> When connection is lost mid-operation the device is left in a FUBAR
> state. The PC mentality doesn't have any clean-up/reset capability.
> Only the "happy path" is ever designed for.
>
> The big system mentality is:
>
> Assume failure and design around it from the start
>
> Open connection - submit request for device to do something - receive
> unique id/method to monitor from - disconnect
>
> At this point it depends on how far your design needs to go. If it
> needs to be expandable to possibly work on the Web, your front end
> needs to establish itself with some kind of publish-subscribe service
> and wait for a push.
>
> Local network only type solutions are easier and more forgiving. Some
> will use a mailbox type service (don't think email there, because it
> is not). Some will launch their own local service sitting on a
> specific IP port that will accept one or a very limited number of
> messages OF FIXED LENGTH AND SPECIFIC FORMAT. Whatever connects will
> be required to use the previous unique ID that was received. Service
> dies off after some period of time without receiving answer.
>
> The road to Hell is paved with JSON and XML.
>
> Never assume a connection can be maintained or that you can transfer
> as much data as you want during that connection.
>
> Never tie-up a resource you don't need to tie-up.
>
> Throwing hardware at it isn't solving an algorithm problem.

Answer (score 0):

I received a nice answer:

> It mostly depends on what your mobile/Desktop application capacity. If
> they are indeed doing business logic and can have some kind of offline
> business logic, I would go Qt / Qml ( you could also distribute the
> application on the mobile easily with Qt/Qml). That way you can
> recycle the C++ code from the raspberryPi into common lib with std
> C++.
>
> The WebGL doesn’t allow multiple users as far as I known to render the
> GUI into WebGL (correct me if I’m wrong here I haven’t used it yet, so
> take this with a grain of salt), but I don’t see that as a solution
> for multiple simultaneous user into different usage context. I always
> saw this option as a good configuration view for a device, a config
> page for a router for example. I’m speculating on this, I haven’t play
> with it, but my understanding so far: If you would need multiple user
> you would need to spawn a webgl process per user connected (CGI script
> or something?!?). And having the business logic into a single process
> that the webgl GUI process access.
>
> But if your GUI are only action controller that are process into the
> centralized business logic, that must always be connected to the
> device, I would go full web browser and can simply wrap you web site
> into an Electron app, saving you a lot of work and have a similar
> experience across the line and reduce the development time
> considerably.

Answer (score 0):

Other comments received:

> ...
>
> But Qt can help with the QML local UI and remote browser WebGL plugin,
> the experimental Qt HTTP server (though I prefer web sockets these
> days)
>
> ...
>
> Last time I tried, it worked, or could work, however concurrency
> management is left as an excercise to the coder.
> https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-65241